# What is the reference for refreshment of some mathematics subjects

Tags: reference-request

I was graduated from Bachelor's degree of computer science in 2006. Right now I am taking a master's degree in computational science. So, last week my classes just started and I was not surprised when I found out that I have forgotten most of the things I studied a decade ago. I have to be frank that I do not even remember exactly even the basic topics like: integral, derivatives, polynomials, etc. They only look familiar to me and I do not remember any basic theorem or law. I need something to refresh my memory so that I can catch up with the classes.

Can anyone please suggest any reference for this?

The subjects I am taking are:

1. Topics on geometry modelling
2. Numeric linear algebra
3. Mathematical optimization
4. Partial differential and sobolev spaces

Comment: I am sure that your university lecturers will be able to suggest books that are ideal for their courses.

Comment: For anyone who is having the same problem as me, later I also found out this website that has been helpful to me aside from the books: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find useful this book (that should be freely available online):

> G. Dahlquist, A. Bjorck, *Numerical Methods in Scientific Computing*.

It is compound by two volumes: the first deals with numerical analysis and the other with numerical linear and nonlinear algebra.

A reference for theory in partial differential equations and Sobolev spaces is

> H. Brezis, *Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces Partial differential equations"*

(it is however a highly level mathematical book)

A good book for general references in many basical mathematical topics is

> M. Boas, *Mathematical methods in the physical sciences*

(contains no proofs but many tricks and procedures; it's not a book for mathematicians.)

Since you have a degree in computer science, I think you know Knuth; in such a lot of things, I guess you may find something useful!

However, I can't be sure that these books are suitable for your courses, obviously, hence ask to your lecturers is surely the best idea.

Comment: Thanks so much Federico, I will start with those books.